# PDF with Shogi Zukou and Shogi Musou

Tags: shogi

I'm very interested in Shogi, and I have a board I bought from USA (I'm in México).

So of course I'm interested in Shogi tsume (mating problems), eventually I came to hear about Shogi Zukou by Kanju Itou, and Shogi Musou by Soukan Itou III (the third).

However I've come across a bit of a problem, I can't really find any one source for all the problems, at least an English one...

So, is anyone aware of a PDF file (preferable) or some kind of file that has all these problems compiled? Along with their solutions of course. If they could use images or kanji instead of pure text, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

A web search for *tsume shogi* reveals lots of sites with Shogi mating problems.

I'm not aware of a specific compilation of Shogi Zukou and Shogi Musou, but if it's a pdf you want I did discover [this compilation](https://sites.google.com/site/fatboldcyclopsplace/the-goods) of 300 problems in pdf form.

Comment: Oh that's awesome! Thanks! I'm aware that they offer the problems, but what I was looking for was a compilation, this helps out a lot, thanks! I won't accept this answer just yet, in case somebody has something more specific. :)